# Hybrid mobile SP2013 client

Tags: rest, mobile, json

I already have a native iOS app that uses SP rest api without issues.
My plan is to port this app into a hybrid one and make it cross platform using Cordova.
Basically I want to mimic the native behavior, load a bunch of html and js locally (because I want it to be fast) and make ajax request to SP services.

Has anyone ever tried to achieve something like this?
Right now I'm facing the same-origin policy issue. Any hints are appreciated.